# Do Google results differ between states? Sales are not coming from expected regions despite appearing to rank

Tags: seo, geolocation, search-results

I manage a website that sells snow-related products. It ranks pretty well in Google. Oddly though, of the states that typically receive snow in the US, in 2015, only people from 2 states have purchased products. This just seems strange and I'm trying to figure out why this would be the case.

Is there any way to tell from what states you are getting traffic from? I see in Google Analytics that I can see what cities, but there are only a few listed. There are two other sources that say "(not set)" and "...". Is it possible that Google is showing different results to people searching from other states?

Answer (score 2):

It could be the case that, in the states with more snow, there are more companies that offer similar services/products to yourself. If this is the case it may explain why you've had only 2 sales in these states, due to the higher level of competition online.

You can check visitors from specific states within Google Analytics: 
Audience > Geo > Location > Countries > United States > Region.

You will need to set your secondary dimension as 'Region' to include this in the report.

Answer (score 1):

The most exact method would be to merge IP adresses from your access.log file with any GeoIP database.

Beside of this i would deeply dive into querying Google with your keywords but from different states, using near search parameter, like `https://www.google.com/search?q=ski&near=boston`

Google means such things, like you sell, have local binding. Try to search with the URL i cited above and you will see the local pack on SERP, which gives out shops Google means are mostly relevant to the search area. If people are searching and let Google utilize their geoposition, they don't need to search `ski near boston`, but only `ski` - and Google already means they want a local results. So it can happens, that your site indeed ranks not everywhere.